# class according to the specifications in the template file usresident

Tags: python

In this problem, you will implement a class according to the specifications in the template file usresident.py. The file contains a Person class and a USResident class (a subclass of Person). Person is already implemented for you and you will have to implement two methods of USResident.

For example, the following code:

```
a = USResident('Tim Beaver', 'citizen')
print a.getStatus()
b = USResident('Tim Horton', 'non-resident')
```

will print out:

citizen

### will show that a ValueError was raised at a particular line

### DO NOT MODIFY THE IMPLEMENTATION OF THE Person CLASS

```
class Person(object):
def __init__(self, name):
    #create a person with name name
    self.name = name
    try:
        firstBlank = name.rindex(' ')
        self.lastName = name[firstBlank+1:]
    except:
        self.lastName = name
    self.age = None
def getLastName(self):
    #return self's last name
    return self.lastName
def setAge(self, age):
    #assumes age is an int greater than 0
    #sets self's age to age (in years)
    self.age = age
def getAge(self):
    #assumes that self's age has been set
    #returns self's current age in years
    if self.age == None:
        raise ValueError
    return self.age
def __lt__(self, other):
    #return True if self's name is lexicographically less
    #than other's name, and False otherwise
    if self.lastName == other.lastName:
        return self.name < other.name
    return self.lastName < other.lastName
def __str__(self):
    #return self's name
    return self.name

class USResident(Person):
""" 
A Person who resides in the US.
"""
def __init__(self, name, status):
    """ 
    Initializes a Person object. A USResident object inherits 
    from Person and has one additional attribute:
    status: a string, one of "citizen", "legal_resident", "illegal_resident"
    Raises a ValueError if status is not one of those 3 strings
    """
    # Write your code here

def getStatus(self):
    """
    Returns the status
    """
    # Write your code here`enter code here`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We can't really help you until we get a clear description of the problem you're solving, the error you're getting, the minimal code to reproduce the error, and a clear indication of what result you expected.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with the replies to this post concerning MCVE.

As for an answer to the question (to get the grader to accept your answer), remember that when inheriting the (Parent) `class Person` for (child) `class USResident`, (Parent) `class Person` will need to be initialized in (child) `class USResident` with:

`Person.__init__(self, name)`

So the code that gave me a correct answer was:

```
class USResident(Person):
""" 
A Person who resides in the US.
"""
def __init__(self, name, status):
    """ 
    Initializes a Person object. A USResident object inherits 
    from Person and has one additional attribute:
    status: a string, one of "citizen", "legal_resident", "illegal_resident"
    Raises a ValueError if status is not one of those 3 strings
    """
    Person.__init__(self, name)
    if status != 'citizen' and status != 'legal_resident' and \
        status != 'illegal_resident':
        raise ValueError()
    else:
        self.status = status

def getStatus(self):
    """
    Returns the status
    """
    return self.status
```

The final exam is over but you can go to Final Exam Code Graders in the sidebar of the course to check this code.

I started this course late so I just got to this question and I too was perplexed as to why I wasn't getting the "correct" output as well (for upwards of an hour!).

For those of you not in the course, here's a picture:

[image: correct output for final exam problem 5]

The course, for those who are interested, is "Introduction to Computer Science and Programming Using Python", or 6.00.1x, from [edX.org](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-computer-science-mitx-6-00-1x-6) .

Unfortunately, only enrolled persons can access the code grader.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is very simple, just to test you if you can use a constant in the class.

Just like something: `STATUS = ("c", "i", "l")` and then raise the `ValueError` if the condition failed.